# Default Silverlight splash screen missing (but only in CRM 2011)?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, silverlight-5.0

Something weird is happening.

My Silverlight applications for CRM 2011 are missing their default loading splash-screens.

I can create a simple Silverlight app without setting the `RooVisual` element...

```
        //this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
```

which will create an "endlessly loading" effect. Normally, if I run it via the debugger or host it in an IIS, it's as you'd expect: I get the typical SL loading indicator. However, if I place it in CRM 2011 web resource (doesn't seem to matter if it's a local CRM installation or online) and use that as part of a form, I just get a white rectangle.

Now, so far, all my SL controls are used in local installations, so loading times are non-existent. However, I'm creating a solution which might end up being used on-line, and leaving it as it is, a client could think the application has hung-up or crashed while in fact it is still downloading.

I've also tried using a custom splash-screen, with the same results.

What could possibly be wrong? Is this some documented (or undocumented :P) CRM feature that I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it!

The issue, as it turns out, is naming the CRM resources with a .xap on the end, for example `new_mySL.xap`.

I could swear that we didn't do it in our older projects and that the splash screens worked correctly... as such, I don't know if there was some CRM update that changed this or perhaps my mind is simply playing tricks on my (quite possibly the latter).

Answer (score 1):

Well in our CRM 2011 environments they always show the Silverlight loading screen, so I'm not sure why they aren't displaying for you.

Have you tried just a generic 3rd party silverlight application?

One thing you could do is have an HTML web resource that has a loading screen on it and then using your silverlight application hide the loading screen (which it will do only after it's loaded).

Comment: That's what I ended up doing (a HTML page with a loading indicator). Do you have any Silverlight controls running in CRM Online? If not, could you please confirm if your controls still keep their loading indicators there? I could swear we used to have the loading indicators as well at some point in the past, when I think about it, and I'm wondering if some rollup didn't disable them...

Comment: We have Silverlight in our online environment and still have the blue orb loading indicator.

Comment: :/ I really have no idea what is going on... I come back home, and create a new SL project on my own machine (so it's not a machine config thing), and deploy it directly to CRM Online... and I still get the white rectangle. :( I don't suppose you'd have any suggestions on how I could try and diagnose this further? The loading indicator I made in HTML is OKish (just a spinning GIF, really)... it's not ideal.